# XAML button not triggering on click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I have a XAML layout (see below), with a number of buttons. They were all previously working, but since I have updated some of the sizes and positions, one is not working any longer? It appears, but clicking it doesn't trigger the relevant C# code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My_App;assembly=My_App"
             x:Class="My_App.HomePage"
             Title="Home Page">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="7, 40, 7, 10" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
           <Button x:Name="NewDeviceButton" Image="add.png" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
```

The C# code is as follows:

```
namespace My_App
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        // Class Definitions 
        IAdapter adapter;

        public HomePage(IAdapter adapter)
        {
        NewDeviceButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
            debug.writeline ("Button Press");
            devices.Clear();
            adapter.StartScanningForDevices (0x180D.UuidFromPartial ());
        }
    }
}
```

I really can't understand why the button is rendering and displaying correctly, but not functioning?

Comment: Does that even compile ?

Comment: @LucMorin Yes, although I have left out lots of the other code, these are only the bits linked to the troublesome button

Comment: ahh, sorry, I just realized it's xamarin stuff... don't mind me ;-)

Comment: add something simple like a console output to the event handler so that you can make sure it actually fires.

Comment: @FarhanAnam There is a debug line at the start of the code (I'll show it now) which sin't firing, so we aren't getting to the code

Comment: where do you put the c# code?

Comment: try a separate method instead of the lamda expression.

Comment: i mean where do you put the c# code you specified? (in which method)?

Comment: @FarhanAnam I have edited the code to show C# context, not sure how else I would structure this, as this seems to be the recommended Xamarin layout. Also, remember this button worked when I had a different layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem! The button's row and column were both defined as 40px. I think this over constrained the button and stopped it from working? Changing the row size to `auto` solved the issues. Although has now thrown up several more [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269257/xml-layout-moving-on-button-press?noredirect=1#comment54359151_33269257) with the layout!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you forgot to change the namespace in your code?
I see that in your Xaml file you use `Gas_Sense` namespace, while your C# code references `My_App` namespace...
(just checking - please don't feel offended:-).

And another guess: how do you create your `HomePage`? 
If it is created automatically from Xaml, the problem could be that only default constructor is called and not the constructor accepting `IAdapter` parameter. Try to move your debug line to the beginning of your constructor and see if you get to `Clicked +=` line.

Comment: Have updated the question, the namespaces are fine, it is just me copying it over badly :) I'll do the debug work now

Comment: I have a debug line both sides of the constructor, the code gets to the start of it, but it isn't triggered.

Comment: Hi Grisha, do you have any other ideas for what to check?

Comment: Hi George, like FarhanAnam suggested, try a separate method (not async for starters) instead of lambda expression. Like NewDeviceButton.Clicked += MyHandler;